# tmux won't run as non root user?

Tags: tmux

If I run tmux as root, it runs normally and fully functional.
I created a couple users, and it will not run as any of the users.

```
create session failed: : No such file or directory
```

I checked the outside $TERM is xterm and inside $TERM is screen as FAQs suggest that is most common cause of problems.

I've used tmux regularly on many different systems, but I on this VPS I can't figure out what's up... A little help, please?

EDIT: Thanks to [Jay's](https://serverfault.com/users/39851/jay) helpful advice about strace, I found a permissions problem with /dev/pty*. I fear this won't be a useful post for many others as it seems kind of a one-off problem.

```
strace -f -e trace=file tmux
```

`32000 open("/dev/ptmx", O_RDWR)         = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
32000 open("/dev/ptyp0", O_RDWR)        = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
.....
32000 open("/dev/ptypf", O_RDWR)        = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
32000 open("/dev/ptyq0", O_RDWR)        = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A more general way to solve a problem of this nature:

```
strace -f -e trace=file tmux ..restofyourcommand...
```

Look for `permission denied` / `no such file or directory` errors right before it exits - might find a general reason behind why you're getting this error (that is, see *what* directory it was trying to create, then make it manually and observe the error, it might be that it's trying to make `/home/x/some/dir` without `/home/x/some` existing or something).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm afraid I didn't get any further. I tried messing with permissions on /var/run/tmux but didn't get anywhere. What does getcwd mean?

Comment: Would you like to try with `strace -e trace=all` and paste that in? Not sure what to recommend other than that. `getcwd` just means get current working directory.

Comment: I tried to make some sense of it but I'm lost. Your continued input would be appreciated. New strace output / pastebin link edited in.

Comment: I completely forgot to account for the fact that `tmux` will fork off other processes. Can you try `strace -f -e trace=file tmux ...`? You can guess what I'll ask for next if that doesn't help :-)

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me because my `tmux` *daemon* process was hitting its maximum process limit.

After raising its maximum process limit (cf. [Set max file limit on a running process](https://serverfault.com/questions/201207/set-max-file-limit-on-a-running-process)) I was able to start my new session with `tmux new-session ...`